# IPython метод bind

Tags: bind, ipython

Почему IPython не распознает метод связки события и обработчика события bind? Чем заменить его?

```
def output(event):
y = eval(text1.get())
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
init_printing(use_unicode=False)
tex2 = eval('y.diff(x)')

from tkinter import*
# родительский элемент
root = Tk()
# устанавливаем название окна
root.title("Вычисление производных сложных функций")
# устанавливаем минимальный размер окна 
root.minsize(width=80,height=60)
# включаем возможность изменять окно
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
# поле для ввода функции
lab = Label(root, height=2, text="Введите функцию", font="Arial 18").grid(row=1,column=1)
tex1 = Text(root,width=25, height=2, font="Arial 16", wrap=WORD)
tex1.grid(row=1,column=2)
# поле для вывода производной
lab = Label(root, height=2, text="Производная", font="Arial 18").grid(row=2,column=1)
tex2 = Text(root,width=25, height=2, font="Arial 16", wrap=WORD).grid(row=2,column=2)
# поле для ввода значения производной
lab = Label(root, height=2, text="Введите x", font="Arial 18").grid(row=3,column=1)
tex3 = Text(root,width=10, height=1, font="Arial 16", wrap=WORD)
tex3.grid(row=3,column=2)
# поле для вывода значения производной
lab = Label(root, height=2, text="Значение f'(x)", font="Arial 18").grid(row=4,column=1)
tex4 = Text(root,width=10, height=1, font="Arial 16", wrap=WORD).grid(row=4,column=2)
# кнопка вычислить
but1 = Button(root, height=1, text="Вычислить", font="Verdana 16", bg="grey", fg="black", command=lambda:output).grid(row=5, column=1)
# кнопка подставить
but2 = Button(root, height=1, text="Подставить", font="Verdana 16", bg="grey", fg="black").grid(row=5, column=2)

but1.bind('<Button-1>',output)

# запускаем главное окно
root.mainloop()
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ---> 43 but1.bind('Button-1',output)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Comment: Покажите код, `but1` не имеет метода `bind()`

Comment: В начале кода пытаюсь из текстового поля tex1 вставить формулу в sympy для нахождения производной и полученную производную вывести в tex2. Наверняка есть ошибка.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `print()` для понимания, что у Вас там происходит

Comment: в какую часть кода?

Comment: Добавьте везде, где Вы не уверены что именно происходит,посмотрите в сторону инструментов дебага